# How to login using Bootstrap and PHP?

Tags: php, authentication

I am currently building a small application to manage the amount of comic books I have at the present. I am using MVC in notepad++, I would have used a framework however it isn't a large application so didn't see the need of one. I am using PHP backend and Twitter Bootstrap as the front end however I am having a snag when logging in using Sessions. I have registered using the application which works no problem however when I try to login with the credentials it just keeps loading index.php instead of login.php.

**View**

header.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>My Comics</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()" style="background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <!-- If email is does not equal email in database then remain in index page -->
        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Email']) && $_SESSION['Email'] <> ''): ?>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
         <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="container">
          <!-- If email does equal the one given in database login to profile -->
          <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Email'])): ?>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>       
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">My Comics</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>                  
                </ul>                 
                   <!-- Display logout button along with users email -->
                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Email']) && $_SESSION['Email'] <> ''): ?>
                    <div class="navbar-search navbar-brand pull-right">
                        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['Email'])): ?>
                            <form action="logout.php" method="post">
                               <!-- Welcome message for user with logout button -->
                                <?php if ($_SESSION['Email'] != "") echo "Welcome " . $_SESSION['Email']; ?>
                                <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="submit" class="btn-danger"/>
                            </form>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  <!-- Login Form for users -->
                <?php else: ?>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="login.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="Email" value="Email" id="Email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="Password" value="Password" id="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                    </div>
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                </form>
                 <?php endif; ?>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
```

**Model** 
LoginData.php

```
<?php

class LoginData {

    protected $Name, $Email, $Password;

    public function __construct($dbrow) {
        $this->Name = $dbrow['Name'];
        $this->Email = $dbrow['Email'];
        $this->Password = $dbrow['Password'];
    }

     function getName() {
        return $this->Name;
    }

    function getEmail() {
        return $this->Email;
    }

    function getPassword() {
        return $this->Password;
    }

    function logout() {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
    }

}
```

LoginDataSet.php

```
<?php

require_once('Model/Database.php');
require_once('Model/LoginData.php');

class LoginDataSet {

    protected $_dbHandle, $_dbInstance = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_dbInstance = Database::getInstance();
        $this->_dbHandle = $this->_dbInstance->getdbConnection();
    }

    public function fetchLoginDetails($Email, $Password) {

        $Password = crypt($Password, $Email);

        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email=:u AND Password=:p"; //basic SQL Query

        $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); //Prepare PDO statement
        //SQL Injection
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':u' => $Email,
            ':p' => $Password
        )); //Executes PDO statement
        $dataSet = [];
        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) { //Fetches the next row matching the query
            $dataSet[] = new LoginData($row);
        }

        return $dataSet;
    }

    public function fetchProfileDetails($Name) {
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * user WHERE Name='" . $Name . "'";

        $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sqlQuery); //Prepare PDO statement
        $statement->execute(); //Executes PDO statement

        $dataSet = [];
        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) { //Fetches the next row matching the query
            $dataSet[] = new LoginData($row);
        }

        return $dataSet;
    }

}

?>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

//session start will always be an email
session_start();
$view = new stdClass();
$view->pageTitle = 'LoggedIn';

require_once ('Model/LoginDataSet.php');

//if submit is pressed
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //check the email and password against the one in the database.
    $LoginDataSet = new LoginDataSet();
    //if email and password matches one in the database
    $view->LoginDataSet = $LoginDataSet->fetchLoginDetails($_POST['Email'], $_POST['Password']);
    //get the variables below using the functions of logindataset
    if (count($view->LoginDataSet) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['Email'] = $_POST['Email'];
        $_SESSION['Name'] = $view->LoginDataSet[0]->getName();

       //continue on to profile page
        header("Location:home.php");
    } else {
        //if incorrect return to index page with error
        $_SESSION['error'] = "logindetails";
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
}

require_once('View/home.phtml');
```

This is what it looks like at the present [image: Problem Index]

This is what it should look like [image: Should Look Like]

I had designed the website first in HTML and then dynamically in PHP which I usually do. However it isn't going to the login.php controller it just keeps refreshing index.php, Is there anything particular that anyone notices that could rectify this so it does login and also that doesn't get rid of the Name of the application and button ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the redirects in your controller, you have a redirect to index.php.  Then start debugging and if you continue to have an issue, post a more concise question.  Read the How to Ask section.

Comment: Hi the redirects are included with an if/else statement, I know that the information I am putting in is correct however it still doesn't log me in like I would like which is a welcome [Email] and logout button replacing the login form in the navigation bar within the header.

Comment: If you're not going to debug and isolate your problem further (my suggestion above) then you're not likely to get help here.

Comment: `session_start()` should be called before any output. Why is `<!DOCTYPE html>` where it is? That's most likely your problem. Enabling `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` would show the error.

Comment: Hi guys it says the problem is an undefined index of Email and Password ? How would I define these in MVC as I already set the variables up or thought I did in LoginDataSet using the method fetchLoginDetails within the login controller ?